# Getting error while Translating the language to English

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am getting error while translating the language to 'English', please see below code, i have tried using textblob and google translator, however getting error in both. Below code, i am using google translator library.

```py
def predict_and_translate(text, target_language='en'):
    if isinstance(text, str):  # Check if text is a string
        text = [text]  # Convert it to a list

    # Convert text to numeric representation using CountVectorizer
    X = CV.transform(text).toarray()

    # Predict the language using the model
    output = model.predict(X)

    # Transform the numeric prediction to text using label.inverse_transform
    predicted_language = label.inverse_transform(output)[0]
    print('Detected language:', predicted_language)

    # Translate each sentence individually using googletrans
    translated_sentences = []
    translator = Translator()

    for sentence in text:
        try:
            translation = translator.translate(sentence, dest=target_language)
            translated_sentences.append(translation.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Translation failed: {e}")

    print(f'Translated text to {target_language}: {translated_sentences}')

predict_and_translate(text_to_predict, target_language)

text_to_predict = "Bonjour mes amis, comment allez-vous?"
target_language = 'en'  # English**
```

and the error message:

```
Detected language: French
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-e5581cb60048> in <cell line: 32>()
     30 target_language = 'en'  # English
     31 
---> 32 predict_and_translate(text_to_predict, target_language)

<ipython-input-118-e5581cb60048> in predict_and_translate(text, target_language)
     15     # Translate each sentence individually using googletrans
     16     translated_sentences = []
---> 17     translator = Translator()
     18 
     19     for sentence in text:

TypeError: Translator.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to_lang'
```

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your googletrans package to alpha version, You can update your package using:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0.
```

Also, I've loosly tried to fix the code issue using the below code:

```
    def predict_and_translate(text, target_language='en'):
    # Translate each sentence individually using googletrans
       translator = Translator()
       translated_sentences = []
       translation = translator.translate(text, dest=target_language)
       translated_sentences.append(translation.text)
       return (translated_sentences)

text_to_predict = "Bonjour mes amis, comment allez-vous?"
target_language = 'en'  # English**
ans = predict_and_translate(text_to_predict, target_language)
print(ans)
```

It will give the output as:
['Hello my friends, how are you?']

Please check your code and try to update as per your requirement.